# Using different multiple check boxes to write to the same cell

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, userform

I'm trying to get different multiple check boxes to write to the same cell without overriding previous info.

```
If CheckBox13.Value = True _
    Then
    Range("A1").Value = "True 1"
End If

If CheckBox14.Value = True _
    Then
    Range("A1").Value = Range ("A1").Value + "True 2"
End If
```

Does that look accurate?

Answer (score 0):

Taking advantage of the controls' default property, you could use something like this:

```
Range("A1") = ""

If CheckBox1 Then Range("A1") = "True 1"
If CheckBox2 Then Range("A1") = Range("A1") + ", True 2"
If CheckBox3 Then Range("A1") = Range("A1") + ", True 3"
If CheckBox4 Then Range("A1") = Range("A1") + ", True 4"

If (Range("A1") <> "") And (Left(Range("A1"), 1) = ",") Then
  Range("A1") = Mid(Range("A1"), 3)
End If
```